# Ext3 system calls during file creation and modification

Tags: filesystems, ext3, system-calls, ext2

I'm trying to learn more about Linux and its file system and I'm stuck on understanding the difference between the `ext3` and `ext2` file systems with regards to system calls during file creation and modification.

I understand the fundamental differences between `ext2` and `ext3` up to this point.

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You will have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you are really asking but answer is probably:

**There is supposed to be no difference between filesystems**. Syscalls and VFS are filesystem-agnostic. POSIX standard defines most of what file operations do, as far as `stat` fields are concerned, thus defining when and how atime alike fields are updated. That said, filesystems have their own quirks, but probably not regarding what you ask.